# Prevent Windows 7 from hiding tray icons

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, icons

I have a Windows 7 installed at my workstation and it is always try to hide one or more icons in tray (putting them to grouping arrow). Unfortunately these icon is very important for me as they notifying me about new messages in Skype, TheBat!, ICQ etc. But I can not see these notifications immediately and should to check icons under grouping arrow from time to time. It is very uncomfortable!

Yes, sure, I've tried to set a radio "Always show all tray icons" but it is just don't work, and these icons just disappearing (since there is no grouping arrow anymore, I even can not show these icons back).

I've tried REGEDIT with some recipes, but it not helped me.

Comment: Here's how you are supposed to officially do it, but your registry tweaking may have wreaked havoc.   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-how-icons-appear-in-the-notification-area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you are supposed to officially do it, but your registry tweaking may have wreaked havoc. 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-how-icons-appear-in-the-notification-area

Right-click an empty area on the taskbar, and then click Properties.

Under Notification area, click Customize.

For each icon, select one of the following options in the list:

- Show icon and notifications. The icon always remains visible on the taskbar in the notification area and any notifications are displayed.
- Hide icon and notifications. The icon is hidden and notifications aren't displayed.
- Only show notifications. The icon is hidden, but if the program triggers a notification balloon, it's displayed on the taskbar.

Click OK.